# How is transaction handled in JBOSS for asynchronous jax-rs client?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, jboss, transactions, jboss7.x

I was trying to understand how container managed transactions are handled for asynchronous jax-rs client in JBOSS.

If the following code is executed within a transaction in JBOSS then does the same transaction continue when the asynchronous response is received in another thread? Or does JBOSS end the transaction when the requesting thread completes (response comes on different thread)?

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
final WebTarget target = client.target("http://quote.com/quote/RHT");
target.request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<String> {

   public void completed(String quote) {
       System.out.println("RHT: " + quote);
   }

   public void failed(Throwable t) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on experiment, it appears the transaction continues until the async operation is completed.